# Issue with wordpress pagination: last 2 posts show again on second page

Tags: posts, pagination

I've enabled pagination for one of my pages where I'm pulling the latest news articles from.
This is the code:

```
<div class="container white" style="padding:50px 0;">
    <div class="container-max">
        <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1';

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'offset' => 2,
            'post_status'=>"publish",
            'post_type'=>"post",
            'orderby'=>"post_date",
            'cat'=>'-8, -9, -7, -6, -5, -4',
            'paged'=> $paged
        );

        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        ?>

            <div class="latest_new_posts main-news">

                <?php
                $wp_query = new WP_Query('$args'.$paged);

                    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :

                        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : the_post();

                            foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
                ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative; margin:45px 0;" >     <div class="blog-date-news main-news-date"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>   <div class="blog-container main-news-container">    <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>   <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(500); ?> </div>      <div class="news-blog-more main-news-blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src=""/></a></div> </div>    </div>

                <?php
                            endforeach;

                        endwhile;
                ?>
```

As you can see I've set `'offset' => 2` as the first 2 posts shouldn't be displayed. Now this work, however when you go to the second page the last 2 posts from the first page show again.
So for example I've got 4 posts on page 1:
Post A, Post B, Post C and Post D
On the second page it will then show:
Post C, Post D, Post E, Post F

This doesn't happen when you go from the second to the third page.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The offset argument is known to break pagination in WordPress and indeed there is a fix. I could explain it all here but there is a topic on it in the WordPress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination#The_Problem

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this code.its perfect working and already tested.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if ($paged == "1") {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'offset' => 0,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
} else {
    $offset = $paged * 5;
    $offset = $offset - 5;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'offset' => $offset,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
}

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            /*Your Code */

endwhile;
?>
<div class="pagination-grp">
    <?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    //$i=1;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'prev_text' => __('<'),
        'next_text' => __('>'),
        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages

    ));
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```